# What is the meaning of pdf_literal whatits mode values?

Tags: pdftex, luatex

In the `luatex` manual, in the 'Nodes' chapter, the `pdf_literal` whatits node is said to have a `mode` field that can take three integer values that are associated with `pdftex` keywords:

- `0` for `setorigin`,
- `1` for `page`,
- and `2` for `direct`.

I can find a reference in the `pdftex` manual for both `page` and `direct` but not for `setorigin`. What does it mean?

By the way, an example showing the three different behaviors would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd guess from the name it evaluates with the `(0,0)` origin at the current point and the following seems to confirm that. It corresponds to the default, no keyword use of pdfliteral:  not using a `setorigin` keyword in the TeX syntax despite the manual hinting that might work.

[image]

```
\protected\def\pdfliteral        {\pdfextension literal}



1 \pdfliteral direct {0 0 m 100 100 l s}

2 \pdfliteral page {0 0 m 100 200 l s}

3 \directlua{
local nd = node .new(8,16)
nd.mode=0 % setorigin
nd.data='0 0 m 100 50 l s'
node.write(nd)
}

4 \pdfliteral  {0 0 m 200 10 l s}

\bye
```